# POST call accepts x-www-form-urlencoded but refuses JSON

Tags: java, spring, web-services, post, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a `POST` call.
 My body has just one parameter so I want to read it simply using `@RequestParam`.
***Code***:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/call", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void doStuff(@RequestParam List<Integer> nums,
                                   HttpServletResponse response) {
```

The call with `x-www-form-urlencoded` works fine-

> curl -X POST    https://localhost:9002/call
>
> -H 'Authorization: bearer d1436121-25f7-4162-b0d4-7699d4acf147'
>   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
>   -H 'Host: localhost:9002'
>   -d nums=0%2C1%2C3

---

But the same exact call with JSON fails.
***Code***:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/call", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @ResponseBody
        public void doStuff(@RequestParam List<Integer> nums,
                                       HttpServletResponse response) {
```

The call `application/json` with fails-

> curl -X POST   https://localhost:9002/call
>   -H 'Authorization:
>   bearer d1436121-25f7-4162-b0d4-699d4acf147'
>   -H 'Content-Type:
>   application/json'
>   -H 'Host: localhost:9002'
>   -d '{
>   "nums":[0,1,3] }'

***Error***:

> {
>       "errors": [
>           {
>               "message": "Leider ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.",
>               "type": "MissingServletRequestParameterError"
>           }
>       ]
>   }

Why does it accept `x-www-form-urlencoded` but refuse `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `@RequestParam` with either URL query params, form data or multipart payloads. If you want to use a JSON payload, you should use `@RequestBody` annotation and map that JSON to a Java object.

From https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

> In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form
>   data, and parts in multipart requests. This is because the Servlet API
>   combines query parameters and form data into a single map called
>   "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of the request body.

Comment: can you please confirm it via some spring reference..thanks

Comment: Updated the answer with the documentation link

Comment: Thanks for the update but the link does not mention anything about the body of POST call.

Comment: The request method doesn't matter. The `@RequestParam` behavior is common for any method.

Answer (score 1):

Your curl command is not formatting the "nums" value correctly. It should be:

```
-d '{ "nums":[0,1,3] }'
```

Comment: I have corrected the formatting, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If its a post request you should use @RequestBody annotation.